# How do i achive the image trail from moving cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make an image trailing when I move the mouse, I already achieved the image to change from the first to the last image when moving the cursor at a certain distance.

JSX :

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './Gallery.css';

export function Gallery() {
  const [ cursor, setCursor ]         = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
  const [ lastCursor, setLastCursor ] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
  const [ visible, setIsVisible ]     = useState(0);
  let distanceX, distanceY;

  function movingCursor(event) {
    setCursor({ x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY });

    const gap = 50; 
    distanceX = event.clientX - lastCursor.x;
    distanceY = event.clientY - lastCursor.y;

    if (Math.abs(distanceX) > gap || Math.abs(distanceY) > gap) {
      setLastCursor({ x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y });
      setIsVisible((prev) => {
        if (prev >= 5) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          return prev + 1;
        }
      });
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div  className="Gallery"
          style={{ 
            display: 'flex',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100vh',
          }}
          onMouseMove={movingCursor}>

          {
            Array.from({length: 6}, (_, i) => {
              return <img 
                        key={i} 
                        src={`./img/${i}.jpg`} 
                        alt="image"
                        style={{
                          position: 'absolute',
                          borderRadius: '5px',
                          top: `${lastCursor.y - 100}px`,
                          left: `${lastCursor.x - 30}px`,
                          height: '200px',
                          visibility: i === visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden',
                        }}
                      />
            })
          }
    </div>
  );
}
```

The question is how do I still show the last image (at its position) when the new image (at a new position )is shown? Do I need to store them in an array or sum? Thank you